# How to open child form within parent form with ribbon in parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, ribbon, mdi

I am having some problem with child form. I would like to open child form inside parent form, and on parent form I have Ribbon (system.windows.form.ribbon).

It does open child form but top of child form hide behind ribbon on parent form, but I would like to have child form right under ribbon.

[image]

Comment: Hi Grant thanks for your prompt response, this is my code             NewEmployee addNewEmp = new NewEmployee();
            addNewEmp.MdiParent = this;
            addNewEmp.Show();
            addNewEmp.BringToFront(); but if I maximize child form then top of child form hide behind ribbon.

Comment: Is that a third party ribbon control?